# How to write cv::Mat to CArchive? (in the MFC function Serialize(CArchive& ar))

Tags: opencv, mfc, mat, carchive

I'm trying to write **matImage**

```
cv::Mat matImage;
matImage.create(480, 640, CV_8U);
```

to a bmp-file (for example "test.bmp") through Serialize(CArchive& ar) in the MFC application.

This code doesn't work

```
void CApplDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        // TODO: add storing code here
        CFile* file = ar.GetFile();
        CString strFileName = file->GetFileName();

        CStringA strFileNameA(strFileName);

        cv::imwrite(strFileNameA.GetBuffer(), matImage);
    }
}
```

How to do this correctly?

**UPDATE**

This code is not good enough, but it works

```
void CApplDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    CFile* file = ar.GetFile();
    CString strFileName = file->GetFileName();
    CStringA strFileNameA(strFileName);

    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        std::vector<uchar> buff;
        cv::imencode(".bmp", matImage, buff);
        ar.Write(&buff[0], buff.size());
        buff.empty();
    }
    else
    {
        UINT size = (UINT)file->GetLength();
        std::vector<uchar> buff;
        buff.resize(size);
        ar.Read(&buff[0], size);
        matImage = cv::imdecode(buff, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        buff.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't that good enough? It seems it's not writing the bitmap header in to file, so it won't work with standard bitmap viewer. Otherwise it should work for your program.

Comment: I've checked it is writing the bitmap header into a file and images are opened by the standard windows image viewer. But I don't like this code anyway, it looks unsafe.

Comment: Why are you using MFC serialization and then throw it all out, reopen the same file that serves as a backing store for the `CArchive`, and write unstructured binary data to it? If you don't need MFC serialization, don't use MFC serialization.

Comment: I don't want. I'd like to use cv::imread and cv::imwrite, but MFC gives only  CArchive (from Serialize function) or I shoud override 'OnFileOpen', write own CFileDialog, GetPathName() and so on.

Comment: You can just as well override [CDocument::OnOpenDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebc8c52a.aspx) and [CDocument::OnSaveDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd83ta1b.aspx). Overriding [CWinApp::OnFileOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk0509s.aspx) is not a bad idea either, since your application can consume multiple file formats, and an appropriate file filter can only be set when instantiating your custom CFileDialog object.

Comment: That's what I looking for. Thank you!